# How to use the tool include-what-you-use together with Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iwyu

I have a standart Visual Studio solution and use MSVS compiler. How can I use include-what-you-use without CMake?

upd:
I used sourcetrail for make compilation_database.json from solution.
Buy iwyu_tool.py -p="path to json" doesn't work with error
What is wrong?

```
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 343, in <module>
    _bootstrap()
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 339, in _bootstrap
    FORMATTERS[args.output_format], args.jobs, iwyu_args))
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 276, in main
    return execute(invocations, verbose, formatter, jobs)
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 239, in execute
    print(formatter(invocation.start(verbose).get_output()))
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 191, in start
    return Process.start(self)
  File "F:\iwyu\include-what-you-use\iwyu_tool.py", line 151, in start
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\Surkov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Surkov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 929, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\Surkov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 441, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

upd2: i want get a file log error ( read comments )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
Change codepage in command line 
use the command: **chcp 65001**